# Some phrases and products for empty text search

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

As a part of empty search in Hybris,we are required to display some phrases and products even when customer does not search anything.

How to go about this scenario?Will we have to make changes in the individual controller methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can return a **searchEmpty** CMS page whenever **searchPageData** doesn't contain the data.
Now you can design the searchEmpty CMS page as you want.

Like the page contains phrases and product components to display phrase and products which can be changed/configured though WCMS.

---

**Edit:**
 As you mentioned in your comment, you want to show static text and products in autosuggestions when the user clicks search box.

Approach 1. 
You can render static text and your selected product data in the hidden container with all pages. Now on search-box click event show that data as autosuggestion dropdown.

Approach 2.
On the search-box click event make ajax call(custom mapping) to get the static data content(JSP).

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply.However I am not dealing with the text search.It is abut the autosuggestions displayed when I search for something.There I am required to display some predefined text and products,when the user just clicks on the search box before typing anything.

Comment: In that case you can make ajax call to get the predefined products data and display it

Comment: I was using the way to keep the codes in a property file and fetch the data from it but is there any way of approaching it through Solr keyword search or something similar?